# TFS 2017 upgrade issue

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

We are currently running on TFS 2015.Update3RC1 (Product Version:14.98.25401.0), while upgrading to the latest TFS 2017 we received an error stating that TFS 2017 does not support SQL server 2012 database instance. So in the next step we installed SQL 2016.

Now moving ahead during the upgrade in Server Configuration Wizard which SQL server Instance should be given as input(SQL 2012 or the new SQL 2016 instance).

Does TFS 2017 upgrade takes care of moving the TFS databases to the new instance of SQL 2016?

If possible please provide the upgrade steps in detail for this scenario: TFS 2015.Update3RC1 (Product Version:14.98.25401.0) (with SQL 2012 DB instance) to TFS 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by crating a new SQL 2016 instance and remapping the TFS databases to new instance, and then upgrading to TFS 2017.

Steps to remap TFS databases : http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/10/22/migrating-team-foundation-server-2013-databases-and-all-databases-in-sharepoint-2013-to-a-new-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Requirements and compatibility for TFS at [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#sql-server). The support SQL Server versions for TFS 2017 are as below:

- SQL Server 2016
- SQL Server 2014

SQL Server 2012 is not supported for TFS 2017.

The general process for upgrading an existing deployment of Team Foundation Server is to:

1. Prepare your environment.
2. Expect the best, prepare for the worst.
3. Do the upgrade.
4. Configure new features.

Details please refer to this article: [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/get-started)

Comment: Resolved the issue by crating a new SQL 2016 instance and remapping the TFS databases to new instance, and then upgrading to TFS 2017.