# How to restore TFS 2015 on TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, backup, restore

i using TFS 2015 on windows server 2008r2 and SQL server 2014.

i want migration to windows 2012 server and Sql server 2016 and TFS 2018.

how can i restore backup TFS 2015 on TFS 2018 with Windows Server 2012 and Sql 2016.

Should the operating system and TFS versions all be the same?

Comment: Hi Morteza Jangjoo, Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Windows Server 2018 version. `Should the operating system and TFS versions all be the same?` No need.

Prior to installing or upgrading an Azure DevOps deployment, better to review the requirements provided in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops). For example, with TFS 2018:

**Supported server operating systems**

[image]

**Supported SQL Server version**

[image]

To migrate TFS2015 to TFS2018, the SQL version on TFS2015 is not support in TFS2018. You need to move the databases to SQL 2016 (minimum SP1)or 2017 first. SQL will do the database upgrade, then you just need to run the TFS upgrade wizard.

As for how to move or clone from one hardware to another for Azure DevOps/TFS on-premises, please kindly refer our official tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops).

For some other notice and details, you could also take a look my reply in this question:  [Upgrade TFS 2015 to TFS 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788360/upgrade-tfs-2015-to-tfs-2018/47794025#47794025)