# TFS 2012 to TFS 2018 Migration/Upgrade Path

Tags: migration, upgrade

Currently I have lots of projects that are in TFS 2012 and would like to migrate them to TFS 2018, maintaining source code history as well as WIT status if possible. I realize that lots of things under the sheets has changed with versions prior to 2018. I would like to know what the proper upgrade path is. Various web sites have mentioned articles and upgrade paths, but none has answered the true question.

Do I have to do TFS 2012 -> 2013 -> 2015 -> 2018 and use the upgrade option at install time. Or can I skip any path all together. Also does the upgrade do the DB modifications in place, or can I copy the DB's somewhere and point to them at TFS version install time? If I am forced to upgrade in place will I loose current TFS functionality. This cannot happen.

Any rules guidance, steps or past experience in this matter would greatly be appreciated.

NOTE: We have made some changes to the standard WIT templates for the 2012 Agile process (TASKS, USER STORIES).

Comment: Did you read the documentation? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started) All of the things you're asking about are covered in great detail.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, afraid you will not find one complete guide in doing this for now. But suggest you could first go through the [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) page. This will help you know the server operating systems, support SQL Server version for each TFS version.

> There are different considerations depending on your configuration,
>   e.g. do you use SharePoint, Reporting Services etc.
>
> One thing that you
>   need to deal with, is that TFS 2012 and TFS 2018 does not support the
>   same versions of SQL server, so you will need to upgrade SQL during
>   the upgrade or move your collection(s) to a new server with the
>   appropriate version of SQL (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391953/complicated-tfs-2017-upgrade)).

Back to your question, not sure if you could upgrade directly from TFS 2012 to TFS 2018. Just find a related chart which showing **the recommended upgrade paths** from various TFS versions (For 2017). However, you definitely not have to do TFS 2012 -> 2013 -> 2015 -> 2018. The worst situation you need two paths.

[image: TFS compatibility]

I would recommend setting up a new server with SQL Server 2016 sp1, where you can migrate your databases using SQL backup. Then first install TFS 2017.1 followed by TFS 2018 and finally updating SQL Server to 2017 (if you need).

Highly recommend doing a trial migration first to validate that things work of  and sort out the process before attempting it on your production server.

---

```
If I am forced to upgrade in place will I loose current TFS functionality.
```

Actually **some old features will not support** any more in TFS2018, such sharepoint, XAML build(the most important missing feature), old work item form. More details please take a look at **[changes to requirements for TFS 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirement-changes-tfs16)**

For work item part, we recommend that you review [handling a TFS 2018 upgrade from old form to new form](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/31/handling-a-tfs-2018-upgrade-from-old-form-to-new-form/) for further guidance.

---

Besides if your TFS2012 installed on a not support system, you may have to first set up a new operating system.

Even though there is not a complete tutorial for TFS 2012 to TFS 2018 upgrade procedure by now. You could refer this article aims to expand on the Upgrade overview and give a step by step walk-through of the [upgrade to TFS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/31/handling-a-tfs-2018-upgrade-from-old-form-to-new-form/). You just need to take care of some notes mentioned above.

The general process for upgrading an existing deployment of Team Foundation Server is to:

1. Prepare your environment. Such as upgrade your SQL sever
   (required), operating system...
2. Expect the best, prepare for the worst. The single most important step you can take here is to ensure you have a complete and consistent set of database backups.
3. Do the upgrade!
4. Configure new features.

Answer (score 0):

One can now upgrade from 2012 to TFS 2018 since the release Update 2 earlier this year. See the documentation for the updated upgrade paths.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started

A key challenge was migrating from older XAML builds to the new builds, but with the release of Update 2 and later you can utilize the XAML build controllers as they are now supported. See the compatibility guide for details.

Plan for downtime - this upgrade is certain to take longer than one from a more recent version!