# Error upgrading to TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

We are trying to upgrade our TFS 2013 Update 5 to TFS 2018 Update 2. I have checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558986/upgrade-from-tfs-2013-update-5-to-tfs-2018?rq=1) to make sure we meet the prerequisites.

From the list, it looks like we met the prerequisites, but when i run the TFS2018 installer it gives me an error saying there is no direct upgrade path from 2013 to 2018. Im not sure why we are getting this error when i looked at the Microsoft site, there is a direct upgrade from TFS2013 update 5 to TFS2018. What am i missing?

Here are our specs on our TFS 2013:

- SQL: SQL Server 2016 SP2
- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
- TFS: TFS 2013 Update5

P.S. we moved the databases to a SQL server 2016 from a 2014 SQL just to comply with the prerequisites.

Comment: What is the **exact** error?

Comment: Hmm seems I have been mistaking. Here is the supported upgrade matrix: Direct upgrade to Team Foundation Server 2018 Update 2 is supported from TFS 2012 and newer. If your TFS deployment is on TFS 2010 or earlier, you need to perform some interim steps before upgrading to TFS 2018 Update 2. Please see the chart below and the TFS Install page for more information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update2

Comment: @jessehouwing i am using TFS2013 update 5 as i have stated

Comment: @DanielMann This is the error when i run the TFS2018 installer "Direct upgrade from Team Foundation Server 2013 is not supported. You must uninstall Team Foundation Server 2013 before you can install this version of Team Foundation Server"

Comment: @rk13 It's telling you what the resolution is: Uninstall TFS 2013, then install TFS 2018. I'd recommend doing a test upgrade first on a separate set of hardware, as well.

Comment: @DanielMann From microsoft's document it says that there is direct upgrade from TFS2013 update5 to 2018. So what are we missing?. If we are to do a complete brand new install(not an upgrade) how can we utilize the current site collections we have on TFS2013?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update2

Comment: It's talking about the project collection databases. A direct upgrade of the project collection databases is possible. Uninstalling the application tier does not impact the databases at all.

Comment: @DanielMann so do you mean i have to take a backup of our current site collection Dbs, and config Db,uninstall TFS2013, install TFS2018, then restore the database? Does that upgrade the site collection Db's and config Db automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh yes, the added error message makes sense. What the TFS installer is telling you is that it can't perform the upgrade while TFS 2013 is installed and running on that server.

You first have to uninstall the Application Tier and Build Services on the machine. This doesn't impact your databases in any way.

Then you can install TFS 2018.2 or 3 directly into that server, point it to the existing SQL databases and it will ask you whether you want to upgrade those.

You'll need to verify a few server settings, plus decide whether you want to enable SSH and Search on this machine.

After the integrity check the installer will install the TFS Application tier and start the database upgrade process.

Only of you're on TFS 2005 or 20008 do you need to perform this step multiple times. first with the 2010 installer before you can take it to 2018. This is what's meant by 'not possible to do a direct upgrade' in some parts of the docs and which confused me at first.

Comment: so do you mean i have to take a backup of our current site collection Dbs, and config Db,uninstall TFS2013, install TFS2018, then restore the database? Does that upgrade the site collection Db's and config Db automatically?

Comment: No need to restore the databases. Uninstalling TFS 2013 won't change the databases. You want the backups in case the upgrade doesn't work. Just uninstall TFS 2013, don't touch SQL, install TFS 2018u2.

Comment: will we still be able to utilize the current Tfs_Config database during the reinstallation of TFS2018? Or will it create a new Tfs_Config db?

Comment: Everything is reused.

Comment: thank you for your answer. We upgraded this week and it worked as expected