# Completly Uninstall TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I wann to Upgrade from TFS 2013 to Azure DevOps Server 2019. I am unable to uninstall the old one, the only thing i can do is to unconfigure the Application Server. But then the installer tells me that an installation is not possible without uninstalling the TFS 2013.

Comment: Did you go to *Add/Remove Programs*?

Comment: Hi, How did it go with this case? was below answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall TFS 2013 from the Control Panel, go to `Control Panel`->`Programs and Features`->`Uninstall a program`.

Before go to control panel to uninstall, you need to remove the configured Extensions(eg. SharePoint Extensions), go to `Team Foundation Administration Console`->`Extensions for SharePoint Products`.

See this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337735/cannot-upgrade-tfs-to-azure-devops-server-2019-because-sharepoint-extensions-are).

Comment: that dosnt work for me because some systemrights (my user was administrator). I used some random uninstaller from the internet

Comment: So you successfully uninstalled the TFS 2013 by using the  random uninstaller. Right? If yes, Could you share the uninstaller and post it as answer to your question?