# Questions needs to asked before we upgrade from TFS 2013 to TFS 2018?

Tags: upgrade

One of our client wants to move from TFS 2013 to TFS 2018. We don't have much information about the current TFS setup at client's end.

Can anyone please guide with what questions we need to ask to client to get the information regarding the current TFS system setup before we start with upgrade process.

Also share if there is any process document regarding upgrading the TFS 2013 to TFS 2018.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm the real requirements first, need to upgrade or migrate?

Check if the current device, OS and software match the [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/tfs/server/requirements?view=vsts) for the upgrade/migration :

> **Client operating systems:**
>
> - TFS 2018 Windows 10 (Professional,Enterprise) Version 1607 or greater
> - TFS 2013 Windows 8.1 (Basic, Professional, Enterprise) Windows 7
>     (minimum SP1) (Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate)
>
> **SQL Server:**
>
> - TFS 2013 Update 4 - SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2012 (minimum SP1)
> - TFS 2018 - SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1)

Upgrade is a full data transfer. You will have all data in the previous TFS.

As TFS 2018 only supports **SQL Server 2017** and **SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1)**, upgrade SQL Server is necessary.

You need to go through article [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started?view=vsts) before doing upgrade. And follow the steps in article [Upgrade scenario walkthrough for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough) to upgrade your TFS. Summarize the steps here:

> 1. Prepare your environment. The first step is to check the [system
>      requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) for TFS 2018. Upgrade SQL Server is necessary for your
>      scenario. Including SQL Server, you also need to check other system
>      requirements and prepare the environment.
> 2. Expect the best, prepare for the worst. You must have a complete and
>      consistent set of [database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan) in case something goes wrong.
> 3. Do the upgrade. Once the preparation is done, you'll need to install
>      the new version of TFS to get new binaries, and then run through the
>      upgrade wizard to upgrade your databases.
> 4. Configure new features. Depending on what version you upgraded from,
>      you may need to [configure each team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) to gain access to some
>      of the new features made available.

Below threads for your reference:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2016/12/22/upgrading-from-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2017/
- [TFS 2012 to TFS 2018 Migration/Upgrade Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554200/tfs-2012-to-tfs-2018-migration-upgrade-path)