# TFS2013 to TFS2017 / Single SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014 AAG

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, alwayson

My current environment is on a single vm:

- TFS2013
- SQL Server 2012 (dedicated instance, installed on the same vm)
- 1 project collection
- Reporting configured

My migration target environment is:

- New VM containing TFS 2017 update 1
- Existing SQL Server 2014 AAG, without SSAS
- Reporting not configured (because of SSAS not installed), and I actually don't need reporting

I tried multiple ways to do this installation, but encountered many problems with Always-On:

1. Upgrade/configure directly with database restore (through SQL Management Studio) directly in AAG, encountered TF400711 error
2. Upgrade/configure without Always-On, works well, but now my problem is to move my databases to AAG. Tfs_Configuration is OK, but when I attach my collection, encountering the TF246017 error. I'm not understanding this error because I use the same connection string than my Tfs_Configuration database...

What is the best procedure in my case?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391953/complicated-tfs-2017-upgrade) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845624/tfs-2017-upgrade-issue) post, but they don't match to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use way2, since Tfs_Configuration is OK, you just need to figure out the error TFS246017. This error can occur due to following reasons

> - Incorrect SQL Installation order especially if you are using Express    edition
> - Database In Recovery
> - Database Out-of-Sync – during migration to newer version of TFS
> - **Permission of Service Account** is not right
> - SQL Database not running or not reachable
> - TFS Proxy not reachable

Double check if you have got enough permission for the installation account. Suggest you go through the **Windows Event Log** , a good candidate where to look for the potential cause.

Also take a look at this thread: [TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database](http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/04/solved-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/) & [this one](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2016/05/24/upgrade-fails-with-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/). There are many resource about this issue in google which may help you figured it out.

Comment: Way 2 was the best way, but I had to detach the collection first, updgrade to TFS2017, move DB, remaps DB (with TfsConfig tool), register DB (with TfsConfig tool) and then attach the collection. I think that my collection was corrupted or Out-of-Sync.. What I have to remember me in my case is that upgrade to TFS2017 in AAG is impossible.